# Saving file to local folder - Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#

**UPDATE - the answer to my question was not actually a true permission issue.**

I ended up solving my problem when I realized I was actually trying to save my file incorrectly. My section of code `httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath)` is *wrong*.

What that ends up doing is trying to save a file to that path which has the `exact` same name as the path as well. To fix this I just appended the file name onto `fileSavePath` and then the file was saved successfully.

So now that section of code looks like this:

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFile.FileName).toLower();
if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".png")
{
    var fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName() + extension;
    var fileSavePath = serverPath + path + fileName;
 
    httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
}
```

P.S. - if you could vote to get this question reopened so that I can provide this answer that would be appreciated, since the post this is supposedly a duplicate of didn't actually end up solving my problem.

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple but I'm getting hung up on this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\TCT-User-2\Source\Repos\Shift_Production\Shift.Web\Content\images\UserAvatars' is denied.

I've looked at some other similar problems here on SO and they all suggest checking to make sure the folder or files aren't read only. As far I can tell they're not but I'm still getting this issue. So maybe it's something else I'm doing wrong in my code?

I'm basically just uploading an image to my `Web API` project and then trying to save it locally to the server.

Here is what I have to do that:

```
[Route("Account/Avatar")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadAvatar()
{
    string serverPath = _appSettingService.GetApplicationSettings().ServerPath;
    string imagePath = _appSettingService.GetApplicationSettings().AppUserProfileImagePath;

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
    {
        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

        if (httpPostedFile != null)
        {
            var fileSavePath = serverPath + imagePath;
            httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: The identity assigned to the application pool running your application needs permission to write to that folder. Generally you should set up an "uploads" folder far away from anything important; give the app pool user permission to it or create a new user specially for your application.

Comment: Go to folder  in server where you want to save your files, right click, properties, security and give permissions to the IIS_IUSRS User, first try "full control", if this works, try with a less permisive permission.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ your comment would have been better off as a response! (And it'd be the same response I'd give.)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I'm currently running the application on my local machine. Does your suggestion still apply? If so, would you mind linking me to a resource/tutorial on how to go about that. I'm still pretty new to all of this so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @codenoir: probably true if it wasn't already a duplicate of another question. Not sure why this isn't getting closed faster.

Comment: @Quiver:Yes, it applies even though you are running locally. IIS defaults to not enough permissions. I like to think it's to protect you from yourself :)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Okay perfect. I'll take a look into it. Thanks again!